# How to remove faucet spray hose

Tags: faucet

I am trying to replace my kitchen faucet and don’t know how to unscrew the spray hose. The ring is getting caught on the spray hose nut and I can’t pull the faucet out. Which is the nut to remove In the attached picture? I also assuming I go counterclockwise on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the picture but there should be three copper tubing extensions coming down from the faucet under the sink. Two are water supply lines - hot and cold - and the other supplies the water to the sprayer. Sometimes these hose are attached to the copper extensions by quick-connect clips sometimes by threaded connections. It appears that yours are threaded. Be sure to turn off the water to both the hot and cold supply lines before disconnecting anything.
You should be able to remove the lines from the copper extensions with a couple of properly sized open-end or adjustable wrenches. The threaded nuts will turn in a counter-clockwise direction (lefty loosey - righty tighty). Hold one wrench on the copper nut and the other on the chrome piece with the flat sides. Turn the chrome nut counter-clockwise when looking up. After you get them off you should be able to slide the ring over all three copper extensions - that's why they are staggered with different lengths. You may also need to remove the weight on the sprayer hose if you have one. They usually just unclip with a little pressure.

Comment: Thanks - that’s what I did and I was able to pull the faucet out. Used two wrenches - one to hold the copper nut and other to unscrew the chrome nut. I went and bought a basin wrench - still tough under the sink.

Comment: @akn  You might want to consider marking the response as the answer.

Comment: @akn - Glad it worked for you.